# Focus where i click on draftjs editor

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

I have an editor made with `draftjs`. If I have previous content, it is filled with that content.

I need to track the clicks. When I click, for example, in the middle of the content and start writing, I will write at the beginning of the editor ... :/

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your component must have been re-rendering some how when you start typing in it. You should stop that re-render or may be assign the newly got state to the Editor if it re-renders